# WP Multisite - How to create a custom "router" for blog prefixes?

Tags: multisite, routing

I'm trying to create a custom route for a WP Mutlisite network.

If you're familiar with WPMS, you know that the db tables for each blog on the network begin with something like `{prefix}_2_`. Normally, visiting `mysite.com/blogname` is what takes you to the blog's homepage. What I'd like to do, is have `mysite.com/2` (look for numeric URI) route to the homepage of the blog whose db tables begin with `{prefix}_2_`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why? What problem do want to solve with that?

Comment: Just clarifying, the number is the blog/site ID. And the `{prefix}` is common to Multi or Single Site.

Comment: That's correct, @brasofilo. Obviously I was brain-dead by the time I posted this question.

Comment: @toscho I wouldn't say it's a problem, I just have several reasons for wanting to do things a little differently.

Comment: 26750, you have a cool avatar, what about putting you nick/name in your profile? ;)) ::::::::::::::::::::: You can [edit] your Question whenever needed (add new info, clarify things, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a URL Rewrite (`.htaccess`) answer, but a simple solution is giving the site name its ID.

> [image: site name as id]

---

Not related, but useful: add a column with the site ID in the Sites screen (`/wp-admin/network/sites.php`).

Drop the plugin in the `mu-plugins` folder.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Multisite - Add Site ID Column
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: brasofilo 
 */

add_filter( 'wpmu_blogs_columns', 'brsfl_get_id' );
add_action( 'manage_sites_custom_column', 'brsfl_add_columns' , 10, 2 );
add_action( 'manage_blogs_custom_column', 'brsfl_add_columns' , 10, 2 );
add_action( 'admin_head-sites.php', 'brsfl_add_style' );

function brsfl_get_id( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['blog_id'] = __('ID');
    return $columns;
}

function brsfl_add_columns( $column_name, $blog_id ) 
{
    if ( 'blog_id' === $column_name )
    {
        echo $blog_id;
    }
    return $column_name;
}

function brsfl_add_style() 
{
    echo '<style>#blog_id { width:7%; }</style>';
}
```

Comment: I went with a combination of your suggestion (use ID as site name) and an Apache rewrite:

Comment: .htaccess:
`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$2?blog_id=$1`

functions.php:
`add_action( 'parse_request', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite()
{
 if ( is_numeric($_GET['blog_id']) ) {
  switch_to_blog($_GET['blog_id']);
 }
}`

get next blog ID for blog name when creating new blog:
`
wp_update_network_counts();
$blogName = get_blog_count() + 1;
`

Comment: The idea is, I'm starting with just blog IDs in the URL for the early stages of my network, and at some point in the future (I have my reasons) I plan to allow site admins to claim a custom URL (site name).

@brasofilo sorry, I'm new here (obviously) and I couldn't figure out how to "claim" this question in my "real" account :-/